# Как можно использовать Lock в Tarantool

Tags: java, spring, tarantool

**Причина поиска:**

У нас на проекты был Redis, но из-за объема данных мы вынуждены переходить на тарантул и возникает проблема малого количества информации, ну либо я плохо ищу.

**Немножко о:**

У нас приложение работает в 6 инстансах. На Java-spring.

**Общий принцип работы:**

Приходит запрос по ресту и мы должны достать из редиса данные, по определенным условиям обновить их и сохранить обратно. И вернуть ответ. Но так же к нам может прийти обновление данных асинхронно через брокер (кафка), поэтому мы делаем лок на запись в редисе через **RedisLockRegistry** и далее работаем с ней, по окончанию обновлений освобождаем.

Так вот и собственно сам вопрос. Как можно мигрировать с редиса на тарантул с учетом такой логики? И можно ли это сделать?